# Propositional logic: Proving equivalence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given two logical forms: $(p \implies q) \lor (q \implies r)$ and $p \implies r$, are they logically equivalent?

Explain your answer.

Thanks! My answer is no and I used coversion theorem to show that the $\mathsf{LHS} \equiv ( p \lor q ) \implies r$

Comment: Why not use truth tables?

Answer (score 1):

The LHS is a tautology, the only possible world makes $(p\implies q)$ false is $p$ is true but $q$ is false, but if $q$ is false, then $q\implies r$ is true.

As RHS is not a tautology, it's clear they are not equivalent. And I think you used your theorem wrongly, as LHS is not $(p\vee q) \implies r $.

Comment: Hello Zafer would you mind adding in your workings please? Thank you once again for taking the time, i really appreciate it

Comment: I think you wanted "[tautology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology)" instead of "totology". The double-arrow can be typed in as `\Rightarrow` $\Rightarrow$ or `\Longrightarrow` $\Longrightarrow$.

Comment: @dtldarek: the long right arrow can be written `\implies`.

Comment: @dfeuer Sure it can, like $\land$ as `\land` and $\lor$ as `\lor` instead of `\wedge` and `\vee`. I just think that when typing code its good to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. @JohnConner Just make a truth table to see what I mean. You know, if..then typed propositions have false value if and only if the conclusion is false even the premise is true. I mean, if $p\implies q$ is false, then $q$ should be false and $p$ should be true.

And, as $q$ is false, then no matter what $r$ is, $q\implies r$ is true. And as the LHS is an "or" statement between this and the other subproposition, then the LHS is always true.

And of course, if $q$ was true, then the LHS would be true again as $p\implies q$ would be true. That's why the LHS is a tautology.

Comment: For completeness, here is one way to show that the LHS is a tautology, without truth tables:
\begin{align}
& (p \implies q) \lor (q \implies r) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"rewrite $\;\implies\;$, twice"} \\
& \lnot p \lor q \;\lor\; \lnot q \lor r \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"excluded middle"} \\
& \lnot p \lor \text{true} \lor r \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify"} \\
& \text{true} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Suppose p true, q true, and r false.  Then, (p⟹r) is false, (p⟹q) is true, and thus [(p⟹q)∨(q⟹r)] is true also.  Consequently, (p⟹r) is not logically equivalent to [(p⟹q)∨(q⟹r)].